# auto refresh MVC view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, refresh

I want to refresh my MVC view using jquery.load and ajax after every 3 seconds. What will be the syntax for this?
I used below code but it didn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
        var url = '<%= Url.Action("Index", "LiveGame") %>';
        $.getJSON(url, null, function() { });
    }
                    , 3000);
});
```

Comment: What didn't work? What did you expect/what is the result?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `load` or `get` jQuery method. `getJSON` return result in JSON format, while your view returns HTML.

Your code might be looking something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        var url = '<%= Url.Action("Index", "LiveGame") %>';
        $('body').load(url);
    }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: It didnt refresh at all. Can you please tell me how to change above code?

Comment: hi @gor: I used your code and it worked. Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

Of course it won't refresh anything - this is an ajax call after all. You must also implement the code that will take the values returned by the ajax method and place it dynamically into the view...

OR you do what @gor is suggesting you - which is NOT ajax btw.

**Edit** Let's suppose that your JSON data returns a `name` field, and that there is an input text field in your view with ID = `txtName`. So that's the (ajax) way to do it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
            var url = '<%= Url.Action("Index", "LiveGame") %>';
            $.getJSON(
                url,
                null,
                function(data) {
                    $('#txtName').val(data.name);
                }
            );
        },
        3000
    );
});
```

Please notice that you are NOT refreshing "the view" - you are individually refreshing each returned JSON value into their corresponding HTML elements. That's what's ajax is about - to be able to dynamically change values, using DOM manipulation, without loading a whole new page from the web server...

That also means that your server-side method should also return a valid JSON object.

This may sound like too much work - if that's the case, and you really just wanna refresh the page without dealing with asynchronous ajax calls and serializing JSON objects, just do what @gor is telling you to do, which means refreshing the whole HTML page each 3 seconds...

Comment: Hi @rsenna: I am new to jquery and ajax. can you please send me the code to do this ?